# Version increment for docker images

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am planning to build an IMAGE with the below command but the command is not executing. Could you please tell me what is the error in the below script?

IMAGE=testimage

```
ID=$(docker build  -t ${IMAGE} .  | tail -1 | sed 's/.*Successfully built \(.*\)$/\1/')
echo $ID
docker tag ${ID} pushdocker/${IMAGE}:${VERSION}
```

here `pushdocker` is my Docker hub namespace

Answer (score 1):

I followed @aron digulla script and it's working fine now.

```
IMAGE=TestImage
VERSION=1.0.0

docker build -t ${IMAGE}:${VERSION} . | tee build.log || exit 1
ID=$(tail -1 build.log | awk '{print $3;}')
```

Answer (score -1):

I am taking Git Commit Level from git and applying it to DOCKER Image as version number.

```
TAG="$(git log --pretty=oneline -1 | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c 1-7)"
echo "LATEST COMMIT NUMBER is $TAG"
and then apply $TAG to docker tag command like below

docker tag image:latest image:$TAG` below is the output.

xyz:latest
xyz:7digitcommit number
```